# Есть необходимость использовать в одном autocomplete два ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, autocomplete

Как сделать так, чтобы оба выполнялись для одного поля типа `input`

```
$('input[name=\'myinput\']').autocomplete({
  delay: 0,
  source: function(request, response) {
    $.ajax({
      url: 'index.php?route=catalog/category/autocomplete&token=<?php echo $token; ?>&filter_name=' +  encodeURIComponent(request.term),
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(json) {
        // autocomplete добавленный который работает 
              $.ajax({
            url: 'index.php?route=catalog/product/autocomplete&token=<?php echo $token; ?>&filter_name=' +  encodeURIComponent(request.term),
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(json) {   
              response($.map(json, function(item1) {
                return {
                  label: item1.name,
                  value: item1.product_id
                }
              }));
            }
          });
        //этот не выводит
        response($.map(json, function(item) {
          return {
            label: item.name,
            value: item.category_id
          }
        }));
      }
    });
  }, 
  select: function(event, ui) {
    $('#category_name<?php echo $module_row; ?>').attr('value', ui.item.label);
    $('#category_id<?php echo $module_row; ?>').attr('value', ui.item.value);
    return false;
  },
  focus: function(event, ui) {
      return false;
   }
});
```

Comment: Как вы потом собираетесь разбираться где чей id? Или достаточно текста в инпуте?

Comment: они возвращают label: item.name, а значение value: item.category_id или product_id думаю можно будет сделать проверку

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Примерно так

```
$('input[name=\'myinput\']').autocomplete({
    delay: 0,
    source: function(request, response) {
        var token = '<?php echo $token; ?>',
            query = encodeURIComponent(request.term);
        // отправляем запросы
        $.when(
            $.getJSON('index.php?route=catalog/category/autocomplete&token=' + token + '&filter_name=' + query),
            $.getJSON('index.php?route=catalog/product/autocomplete&token=' + token + '&filter_name=' + query)
        ).done(function (json1, json2) {
            // формируем список автодополнения путем объединения результатов запросов
            response($.map(json1.concat(json2), function(item) {
                return {
                    label: item.name,
                    value: item.category_id
                }
            }));
        })
    }, 
    select: function(event, ui) {
        $('#category_name<?php echo $module_row; ?>').attr('value', ui.item.label);
        $('#category_id<?php echo $module_row; ?>').attr('value', ui.item.value);
        return false;
    },
    focus: function(event, ui) {
        return false;
    }
});
```

PS. Вообще не советую следовать стилю кода опенкарта. Там кошмар полный

Comment: это и есть opencart =)

Comment: Спасибо за помощь

Comment: Ну зачем же их последовательно-то делать было?

Comment: @DanilRusakov Обновил ответ

Comment: оказалось не так просто сделать проверку в select

Comment: @DanilRusakov Угу. Я об этом и спрашивал в комментарии к вопросу. Можно извратиться и в `value` запихнуть json вида `{id: 123, type: 'product'}` - это решение "в лоб", оно потребует доработку серверной части. Можно еще data-атрибуты задействовать, но тогда придется перехватывать JS-ом отправку формы и подставлять заполнять доп. поля (и это в серверной части тоже нужно будет учитывать).